# How to fix Could not connect to Appium server issue

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop, appium-java

I'm trying to run the Appium server but it is giving this error
`Could not connect to Appium server URL 'http:// 127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub'. Please check if the server is running and the URL is correct (valid URLs can be found at the start of the Appium server log). If you are using the Inspector's browser version, ensure the server has been started with '--allow-cors'.`

[image]

[image]

I have unabled the --alloe cors and the server is already running in the 127.0.0.1:4723